# Almost everything disabled in MS Access

Tags: vba, database

I received an Access database to work with today but it is locked somehow and I'm new to this so I don't know how to unlock and customize it according to my liking.

There is no ribbon showing, only file menu is visible and that too is just showing print, feedback and exit. Nothing else.

Also right click is not working anywhere in the database.

Please tell me how can I unlock this so I can edit its appearance and features. I am attaching a screenshot so you understand better.
[image: Screenshot]

[[image: Screenshot][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/385SY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Access allows users to share secure databases with the users that they specify.

Therefore, you will need to ask the user who created the database to give you access.

Other things, Check the basics, Check for updates, and possibly reboot your PC.